# ASP.net handling all requests for a custom file extension in one ashx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

How can I configure my Asp.net project to handle all requests for a custom file extension like ".coolpix" regardless of the request path in one ashx file.

Comment: Pretty broad, but the most common would be through IIS or the web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an application wild solution, a way to you archieve it, is by adding a handler mapping into your `web.config`:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="myExtensionHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET" path="*.Extension" type="NameSpace.MyExtentionHandlerClass, DLLAssemblyName" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Your `MyExtentionHandlerClass` should implement `IHttpAsyncHandler` or `IHttpHandler`